# MS Word confuses captions and cross-references

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-office

A common error I find with MS Word is that for long documents it mistakenly changes cross-references into the ENTIRE caption the cross-reference relates to. How can this be avoided?

An recurring example of this problem:

1. I insert a figure and a caption below it.  No problem yet.
2. I use the cross-reference feature to refer to the figure within a paragraph I am typing (‘only label and number’ option).
3. At first all seems fine, but when I try to print (refresh) the document, MS Word inserts the entire caption AND figure into the middle of my paragraph.
4. The final result is that there are now 2 figures and 2 captions in my document.  The original figure+caption set are as originally positioned, but the unwanted set are inside my paragraph thus completely destroy the paragraph layout.

To fix the problem I need to manually delete the unwanted figure+caption set and readd the cross-reference.  The problem disappears for a while, but then as my document starts to get longer the problem reoccurs.  It is hugely problematic when working with many images/cross-references.

I have authored many MS Word documents, using different versions over many years and have consistently had this problem.  It is very frustrating and I am on the verge of moving to Latex!

This is a long standing problem – is there a workaround? I am almost sure anyone who has authored a long word document with images has encountered this?

Thanks

Comment: For your personal culture give it a look to `LaTex` as alternative to the program you are using. Please add the  word version.

Comment: @hastur or FrameMaker...

Answer (score 0):

I've always thought that was copy/cut and paste extending the hidden bookmark.  But yes I run into it a lot , now that I'm senior and I only review other people's work  I tend to draw red lines around it and say fix Reference.

I did look at writing a macro to iterate the hidden bookmarks , those starting with underscore, and if they appeared too long or contained a picture , reduce there length. But in the end I found it unreliable and reverted back to manual methods. 
So yes I see it a lot and I'm not really sure how it happens, however I don't delete and reacreate the reference.  I've generally reverted to creating my own named bookmarks and using these in the cross reference field, or as a I said telling others to fix it.